# Is there a way to install new software on ARM64 Ubuntu on M1 Mac running on Parallels?

Tags: macbook, 21.10, arm64, parallels

There is no software center, Pamac, or whatever it is called in Ubuntu.  I can run what is installed and I can update to 21.10 but there is no way to install new software.  Is that on purpose because there is little that is compatible with an M1 Mac or is this a glitch?

Comment: pamac is associated with Arch Linux, not Ubuntu. Ubuntu is in the Debian family which uses dpkg and apt. It's not clear from your question how you installed Ubuntu on this hardware. It's also not clear what software you are trying to install. Edit your question and include more context and details. You should tell us how Ubuntu is installed (bare metal, VM, etc). You should also tell us exactly what software you are trying to install, and the exact problem you are encountering alongside the steps needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Running in Parallels is a virtual machine so no, nothing you hypothesized is applicable. It wasn't correctly installed, that's all.

Comment: Sorry I misread @parallels. Can you set it up to use x86-64? There's more software available under that architecture than there is available for ARM

Comment: Your question should include a real example of something you tried to install, and the complete resulting error message. The description right now ("*no way to install new software*") is too vague to offer useful advice.

Comment: The question is obvious, I can't install software because your software install program doesn't exist on the ARM64 install that's running in Parallels.  Making a snarky comment that Pamac is part of Arch is not helpful.  I'm well aware of this fact.  I'm only using Pamac to describe the situation because I didn't know what you call your software center in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have to agree with Bryan. It's a simple question and the answer is either yes there are limitations on an M1 Mac running under Parallels 17, or there are not. If not, there is a tech support request he needs to make. Otherwise no one has answered his question.
Looking for Parallels/Ubuntu Arm64 questions on Google, I find little of use, which implies that not many people are using it in anger and are satisfied with the limited apps included in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Pamac is an app store for Arch Linux and derivatives.

In Ubuntu, you can install GNOME Software instead. To install it, open a terminal and run the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Afterwards, you can install the GUI of GNOME Software to install other software.

Alternatively, you can use the terminal `sudo apt install name-of-software`

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: "sudo apt install name-of-software" does not work for the software OP had in mind.

Comment: OP wanted to install software, and thought pamac could do that (an XY question). I told OP how to install software.